# Add serverside onclick event to programmatically created div

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, onclick

[Coding in ASP.NET]

I am creating a page where divs are created in code behind as content is loaded from an SQL database.

I have a div that contains the number of votes users have given the current data and when you click on it I want the number of votes to go up by one. This would require executing a query and reloading the update panel. (I do not want Postback)

How can I create an onclick event for the programmatically created div that calls a c# method (with the query)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a bit of digging I found a solution that works quite well and was easy to implement.

I had to create an asp:Button programmatically for the event:

```
Button divButton = new Button();
divButton.Attributes["style"] = "display:none;";
divButton.ID = "divBtn_" + id;
divButton.Text = id;
divButton.Click += divButton_Click;
```

When I create the clickable div do the following:

```
div.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return divclick(" + sqlID + ");");
```

This calls the following javascript:

```
<script>
function divclick(id)
{
    var button = document.getElementById('divBtn_' + id);
    button.click();

    return false;
}
</script>
```

Which calls a button that executes my sql query using the id.